# QGraphicsScene does not update immediately

Tags: qt, qgraphicsscene

I am drawing an ellipse in my graphics scene. When the ellipse is tilted, a portion of its boundary does not appear immediately. After I re-size the window or perform either zoom-in or zoom-out action in my graphics scene, the ellipse boundary is updated and I get the perfect shape that is required.

I have defined my paint function for my ellipse as:

```
QPainterPath ellipse;
ellipse.moveTo(p1.x()+majRadius, p1.y());
ellipse.arcTo(boundingRect(), 0 , 360);
QPen paintpen(Qt::black);
paintpen.setWidth(1);
painter->setRenderHint(QPainter::Antialiasing);
painter->setPen(paintpen);
painter->save();
painter->translate(p1.x(), p1.y());
painter->rotate(theta);
painter->translate(-p1.x(), -p1.y());
painter->drawPath(ellipse);
painter->restore();
```

The definition of my bounding rectangle is:

```
return QRectF(p1.x()-majRadius, p1.y()-minRadius,
              2*majRadius, 2*minRadius).normalized();
```

I have attached a screenshot of two cases of ellipse:
[image]

How to solve this issue?

Answer (score 2):

You didn't show important code, but I think I can guess what is the problem.

When you change some property of `QGraphicsItem` which has impact on `QGraphicsItem::boundingRect()` you should call `QGraphicsItem::prepareGeometryChange` not only not `update`.
See documentation of [QGraphicsItem::boundingRect](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5/qgraphicsitem.html#boundingRect).

Second problem I see is that you have messed up with rotation-translation and bounding rectangle. Try rotate only painter path not the painter itself.

Another issue I can see is that you are saving and restoring a painter in wrong meaner. Saving should happen before you perform any change on painter (in your case before `painter->setRenderHint(QPainter::Antialiasing);)` and restore its state after painting of item is completed (this is Ok).

Comment: Thanks for pointing out so many mistakes. I have followed painter paths example provided in documentation for translation and rotation. Coming to `preparegeometrychange`, I have not been able to figure how to use it, if you could provide some hint.

Comment: Where should I call the `preparegeometrychange` function?

Comment: each method which have impact on `p1`, `majRadius`, `minRadius` and `theta` have impact on `boundingRect()` so this methods should call `preparegeometrychange`.